# jQuery selection on style attribute not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have a html guide exported from a doc file. I'm using jquery to fix some cosmetic issues with the way word exports to html.  My script is working in FF and Chrome, but not in Internet explorer.

Example of my jquery:

```
$("span[style='mso-tab-count:1']").html(' ');
```

Example of the code I use: http://jsfiddle.net/37hqLrcn/1/

Any idea what I can do to make this work across all browsers?

Comment: can you make a different selection of your span?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using, and in what document mode? (Press F12 - the developer tools can tell you.) I seem to remember IE7 (and newer IE versions in compatibility mode) can't cope with selectors that use the `style` attribute.

Comment: Im using IE11, the problem occures in any version of IE. Might there be a problem with the loaded jquery js? open up the jsfiddle link to see the problem.

Comment: may be there could be any other js error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet explorer will add a semi-colon to the end of the `style` attribute and also add a space after the colon, therefore your selector is not matching.

If you want to match exactly, then you will need two selectors:

```
$("span[style='mso-tab-count: 1 dotted;'],span[style='mso-tab-count:1 dotted']").html('  ');
```

There is an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/37hqLrcn/29/) showing it working. IE is being a PITA with iframe security tho, so you can see the result directly [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/37hqLrcn/29/show/)

Comment: In my IE 11 the first link doesn't work and the second shows no content at all.

Comment: Removed `light/` from second link. Now [http://fiddle.jshell.net/37hqLrcn/29/show/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/37hqLrcn/29/show/) works. Thanks, was also new to me.

Comment: Weird, http://fiddle.jshell.net/37hqLrcn/29/show/ works for me in IE, but http://fiddle.jshell.net/37hqLrcn/29 doesnt.

Comment: yes i was having lots of fun with that. it depends if jsfiddle wants to show it in an iframe or not - bizarrely for the exact same URL it occasionally decides to or not. But all that is specific to jsfiddle - as Martin pointed out, it refuses to even load jquery so nothing i can do to get around that

Comment: Yes your right. Well in the end, this solution is working perfectly for me! :) Thanks Rhumborl!